# Airflow in docker keep restarting

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose, airflow

Im trying to create a local Airflow env with Docker + ubuntu in a Windows OS.

I used the following wizard:
https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner

This wizard creates 2 containers (1 for DB and 1 for the Airflow)

Now I'm stuck with the following problem:

My Airflow container keeps restarting after troughing 2 exceptions:

1. "ERROR: You need to initialize the database. Please run `airflow db init`. Make sure the command is run using Airflow version 2.3.2."
2. Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in 
   sys.exit(main())
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/**main**.py", line 38, in main
   args.func(args)
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 51, in command
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/db_command.py", line 35, in initdb
   db.initdb()
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 71, in wrapper
   return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 648, in initdb
   upgradedb(session=session)
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 68, in wrapper
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 1449, in upgradedb
   command.upgrade(config, revision=to_revision or 'heads')
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 294, in upgrade
   script.run_env()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 490, in run_env
   util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
   module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
   spec.loader.exec_module(module)
   File "", line 728, in exec_module
   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 107, in 
   run_migrations_online()
   File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/migrations/env.py", line 101, in run_migrations_online
   context.run_migrations()
   File "", line 8, in run_migrations
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 813, in run_migrations
   self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 548, in run_migrations
   for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 283, in upgrade
   return script._upgrade_revs(revision, rev)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 365, in _upgrade_revs
   revs = list(revs)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/alembic/script/revision.py", line 1040, in _iterate_revisions
   total_space.remove(rev.revision)
   KeyError: '75d5ed6c2b43'"

I tried to run the following command in ubuntu for updating the DB:
"docker exec -it aws-mwaa-local-runner-202_local-runner_1 /entrypoint.sh airflow db upgrade"

but getting same error:
"..... KeyError: '75d5ed6c2b43'"

I also tried to reset and init the Airflow DB with-

1. docker exec -it aws-mwaa-local-runner-202_local-runner_1 /entrypoint.sh airflow initdb
2. docker exec -it aws-mwaa-local-runner-202_local-runner_1 /entrypoint.sh airflow reset
   and still getting the "..... KeyError: '75d5ed6c2b43'" error.

waiting for response,
Thanks

Comment: do you have a particular use case to run this docker? i can suggest better ways of running airflow on local. mwaa local runner is not too useful. i have been running mwaa for an year and have never found this tool useful.

Comment: I would be very happy if you can instruct me what are the other options and how to make them work

Comment: @AlanMil I am having the same issue, any luck with solving this?

Comment: @GalS, nop. In few days I will go back to this issue. Hope to have some positive update

Comment: @AlanMil Thanks, I end up using AF2.2.5 for now...

Comment: @GalS How did you upgrade the airflow version in aws-mwaa-local-runner ?

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal I am using a docker image I am building running on k8s. If that answers your question.